# Find the generating function for the sequence $1, 2, 3, 4, ...$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, generating-functions

In S. Lando's 'Lectures on Generating Functions', we come across the following exercise (1.9a on page 14): find the generating function for the sequence $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...$.

Here's what I did.

Let $$A(x) = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + ... = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}.$$ Let's first note that $$\int A(x) = x + x^2 + x^3 + ... = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} x^{n}.$$ From the book, we know that, by definition, $$\ln \left(\frac{1}{1-x} \right) = x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{3}x^3 + ...  = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}x^{n}.$$ Therefore, $$\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x} \right) \right)' = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ...  = 1 + \int A(x).$$ Hence, $$\int A(x) = \left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x} \right) \right)' - 1$$ and so $$A(x) = \left(\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x} \right) \right)' - 1 \right)'.$$

My question now is: am I done? This is my first time working with generating functions so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Thank you for any help. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose an alternative solution. Consider the geometric series, and differentiate it:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x} \implies
\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

---

Your solution ultimately reaches the same conclusion, on performing the differentiations, though you should note that $\int A(x) \, dx$ should have an unknown constant of integration, so you need to account for that in your process (e.g. independently finding it or by using a definite integral).